# Openlayers 3, get id from selected features

Tags: select, openlayers-3

i have this layer

> ```
>        $.getJSON("/g_estados/GetPrediosJson", null, function (data)
>        {
>
>            var format = new ol.format.WKT();
>
>            var feature = new Array();
>
>            for (i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++)
>            {
>                var fea = format.readFeature(data[i].wkt
>                    , {
>                        dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
>                        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
>                        id: data[i].clave_catastral_g
>                    }
>            );
>                //fea.attributes
>                if (i < 10) {
>                    console.log(fea)
>                }
>                feature.push(fea);
>            }
>
>
>            c_estados = new ol.layer.Vector({
>                name: 'estados',
>                source: new ol.source.Vector({
>                    features: feature
>                }),
>                style: new ol.style.Style({
>                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
>                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
>                    }),
>                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
>                        color: '#ffcc33',
>                        width: 2
>                    }),
>                    image: new ol.style.Circle({
>                        radius: 7,
>                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
>                            color: '#ffcc33'
>                        })
>                    })
>
>                })
>            });
> ```

and some select option like this:

> featuresSelect = new ol.Collection();
>
> ```
>        select = null;  // ref to currently selected interaction
>        // select interaction working on "singleclick"
>        var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({ features: >featuresSelect });
>
>       // select interaction working on "click"
>        var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
>            condition: ol.events.condition.click,
>            features: featuresSelect
>        });
>
>        // select interaction working on "pointermove"
>        var selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
>            condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
>            features: featuresSelect
>        });
>
>        var selectAltClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
>            condition: function (mapBrowserEvent)
>            {
>                return ol.events.condition.click(mapBrowserEvent) &&
>                    ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly(mapBrowserEvent);
>            }
>        });
>
>        var changeInteraction = function ()
>        {
>            if (select !== null)
>            {
>                map.removeInteraction(select);
>            }
>            var value = 'singleclick';
>            if (value == 'singleclick')
>            {
>                select = selectSingleClick;
>            } else if (value == 'click')
>            {
>                select = selectClick;
>            } else
>            {
>                select = null;
>            }
>            if (select !== null)
>            {
>                map.addInteraction(select);
>                select.on('select', function (e)
>                {
>
>                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '&nbsp;' >
>                        e.target.getFeatures().getLength() +
>                        ' selected features (last operation selected ' + >e.selected.length +
>                        ' and deselected ' + e.deselected.length + ' >features)';
>                    //document.getElementById('id01').style.display = >'block';
>                    //console.log(e.selected);
>                    //console.log(e.target.getFeatures()[0]);
>                    console.log(featuresSelect);
>                    //console.log(featuresSelect[0]);
>
>
>                    var features2 = new Array;
>                    feature2 = featuresSelect;
>
>                    console.log(features2)
>
>                    for (i = 0, len = featuresSelect.getLength() ; i < len; >i++)
>                    {
>                        console.log(featuresSelect[i]);
>                    }
>                    //{
> ```

so after i select a feature i want to know the id to call some other function based on this id, but i been stuck in this for hours and openlayers samples and documentation are not getting me enought.

note: i dont seek jquery (i dont know) or other framework, just pure javascript, html, css.

I'm using lastest version of openlayers, thanks for any help.

Comment: ok, i have changed the method to select features by pixel, so its' solved now.

Comment: i have done it, its working now but could not get the features using select, so i change it for select features by pixel and it's done, thanks